# Matching a string to one of many patterns and extracting data

Tags: javascript, regex, url, url-routing

I have a problem I want to solve with RegEx, or any other method if there is a better one. I've tried several ways to achieve the goal, but nothing really worked.

I have an array with endpoints:

```
const endpoints = [
    {
        id: 1,
        url: "/api/items/:itemId"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        url: "/api/users/:userName/delete"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        url: "/api/users/:userName/edit"
    }
];
```

And a request URL:

```
const url = "/api/users/max/edit";
```

Now what I want is to have a function which acts like this:

```
const rewrite = (url, endpoints) => {

    // What is the best way to achieve the following return value:

    return {
        endpointId: 3,
        values: {
            userName: "max"
        }
    };
};
```

Explanation: The function should find the appropriate endpoint for the url. All parts of the endpoint url which start with a colon are not static, but should rather be replaced with values from the request url. In this case `:userName` should be replaced with `max`.

I've been in web development for some time now, but to be honest I've almost no clue how to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const rewrite = (url, endpoints) => {
    var doubledArray = Array.prototype.map.call(endpoints, function(el) {
        return {
            id: el.id,
            url: el.url.split('/')
        };
    });

    var parts = url.split('/');
    var i = 0;
    parts.forEach(function(element) {
        doubledArray = doubledArray.filter(el => (element == el.url[i] || el.url[i].startsWith(':')));
        i++;
    });

    return {
        endpointId: doubledArray[0].id,
        values: {
            [`${doubledArray[0].url.filter(el => el.startsWith(':'))[0].substring(1)}`]: parts[doubledArray[0].url.findIndex(function (el) { return el.startsWith(':'); } )],
        }
    };

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the `endpoints` making each `.url` into a RegExp to test the url against.

When a matching one is found, it is just a matter of extracting the needed part and making up an Object with the property name:

```
<script>
    const myEndpoints = [
        {
            id: 1,
            url: "/api/items/:itemId"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            url: "/api/users/:userName/delete"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            url: "/api/users/:userName/edit"
        }
    ];

    const myUrl = "/api/users/nermal/edit";

    const rewrite = (url, endpoints) => {

        for (let i = 0; i < endpoints.length; i++) {
            var rep = new RegExp(":(\\w+)", "m");
            var propName = rep.exec(endpoints[i].url);

            var reu = new RegExp(endpoints[i].url.replace(propName[0], "(.*)"));
            var a = reu.exec(url);

            if (a !== null) {
                var x = new Object;
                x["endpointId"] = endpoints[i].id;
                var y = new Object;
                y[propName[1]] = a[1];
                x["values"] = y;
                return x;
            }

        }

        return null;
    };

    var q = rewrite(myUrl, myEndpoints);
    console.log(q);
    console.log(q.values);

</script>
```

Outputs:

> Object { endpointId: 3, values: {…} }
>   Object { userName: "nermal" }

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what's needed. Though I'd like to point out that this only works if there is only 1 property in a URL. eg: the pattern `/api/users/:userName/items/:itemId` wouldn't capture the `itemId`

Comment: @Jack Agreed. But at least the OP can develop it from there.

Comment: Beside the problem @Jack pointed out, this does not work if there is another endpoint with the URL ```/api/users/:userName/edit/more```. If the request URL is ```/api/users/nermal/edit/more``` the function returns the endpoint with id 3. I think if you explain the code more, I can figure out the solution. E.g. what exactly does ```(.*)```?

Comment: @Ruudy That line is to make a new regex such as "/api/users/(.*)/delete" in order to extract the, e.g., "nermal" from the url.

Comment: @Ruudy You can use sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to get explanations of regexes. (Remember that `":(\\w+)"` actually has only one backslash because it needs to be escaped in a JavaScript string.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Already played around with this tool, thanks nonetheless.